# Are there any limitations of JQuery Full Calendar control?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar in sales force application, I am facing issue in displaying the data on the calendar. I have large number of data to show on the calendar.

I want to know if there are any limitations of the number of events we can show in the calendar or on a specific date on the calendar?

Comment: *facing issue in displaying the data* what issues are there, would you share?

Comment: I don't think there are limitations to how many events can be shown. But your browser will take some time to render events if there are a lot of them.

Comment: Thanks for reply but the issues is resolved,
There were some quotes in the data being passed to the calendar. I have handled that, are there any more special characters which need to be handled.